# How to allow Windows 7 accept UDP messages from an external device with address "127.0.0.2"?

Tags: windows, udp, broadcast

My firm produces some devices with a network interface. The devices are sent with a IP address = 0.0.0.0. The customers plugs the device on the private net in the field and, by using a tiny app written with VB6, discover it and set the correct IP address.
This working by using UDP messages: the app broadcast a "Who's there?" UDP message, read back the answer(s) containing the MAC address of the device(s), and the the user send another UDP message containing the new IP address for target MAC.

Now, for some unknown reasons, one of these device get its IP address set to 127.0.0.2. The problem is that now the VB app can't find (via UDP) the device anymore, making it impossible to change the IP address to a valid one.

Further analisys revealed than if the app is running on Windows XP it sees the device, but if the app is running on Windows 7 the UDP message does'nt arrive to to the "socket" (while Wireshark can see the answer from the device).

Now, there a solution to allow Win7 to let "pass" an UDP message sent from a 127.0.0.2 external address? If yes, we could avoid to ship around the world a replacement device with a correct IP address and all the trouble of phisically mounting it in the field.

Here's a Wireshark capture of the "question" and the "answer" not "detected" by the VB app:
[cap.pcapng](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2651363/cap.pcapng)

Comment: Stick a Linux machine between the two and configure iptables to translate the address to something less broken.  One may need considerable effort to even get that working.

Answer (score 4):

> Now, for some unknown reasons, one of these device get its IP address set to 127.0.0.2.

You need to fix that.

The 127/8 block is reserved for the "loopback" address (ie. localhost). No packets sent to 127.0.0.2 will leave your systems NIC. Unless there are bugs in the drives (or hardware): this could be the case with WinXP.

Comment: Sorry for not have been clear enough:
The PC with Windows7 receives UDP packets from 127.0.0.2, and will never send packets to that IP. My problems is that Windows7 does'nt currently allows the received packet to "reach" the app (or the socket used by it).

Comment: That the hardware is putting packets from that IP on the network is a defect. That such invalid packets then disappear after "receipt" is not the issue. For more information see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3330.txt *"no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network anywhere"*.

Comment: Ok, i agree, other guys are already changing the hardware firmware. I'd still need a way (even a temporarly one) to make Win7 letting the packets reaching my app so the customer there can set the devices IPs to a legal value.

Comment: Well, I guess you could use Wireshark, since it is seeing the packets in question.  Or another packet analysis tool.